# Image.Source not showing image when using a string formatted binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-4.0

I'm currently using the following code to build a `ComboBox` control with flag images and canadian province names. However the images are not showing up in the control. I have tested the binding and it generated the location properly, but the image just doesn't come up in the control.

Not sure what is wrong here any help would be appreciated

**Code:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb_Provinces" Text="Province"SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"  SelectedValuePath="ProvinceCode" ItemsSource="{Binding Provinces, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel x:Name="stk_ComboTemplate" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Image Width="25" Margin="10" Source="{Binding ProvinceCode, StringFormat=/CanadaTreeSvc.Interface;component/Resources/img/flags/\{0\}.gif}" />

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProvinceName}"/>

                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontSize="10" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding ProvinceCode, StringFormat=/CanadaTreeSvc.Interface;component/Resources/img/flags/\{0\}.gif}"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

**Resulting Output:**

[image]

Comment: Did you try changing {0\} to {0}\?

Comment: `StringFormat` is only used if the target property is actually a `string`, The Image Source property is a `Uri` so the binding won't apply the StrngFormat. You will have to use a `IValueConverter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StringFormat` only works if the target is of type `String`. 
Because `Image` `Source` is of type `Uri` the `StringFormat` will never be used in the `Binding`

The best option would be to make a `IValueConverter` to format the `string` and return it to the `Image` `Source` property.

Example:

```
public class ProvinceNameToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Format("/CanadaTreeSvc.Interface;component/Resources/img/flags/\{0\}.gif", value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ProvinceNameToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ImageConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

..................

   <Image Source="{Binding ProvinceCode, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" />
```

Comment: this worked but i don't understand why the original doesn't work here when i have used a similar method to do this in the past for dice game i wrote a few weeks ago using this 

            <Button Name="TheButton">
                <Image Name="img_Die"  Source="{Binding Value,  StringFormat=/BluffersDice.Interface;component/res/dice/{0:d}.png }" />
            </Button>

Comment: so would you put the c# code in the code behind, what about a more global solution ?